# ActionView::MissingTemplate when trying out Devise Login Items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, actionview, partials

Now, I have to admit, I'm totally new to Ruby on Rails and don't quite understand every concept. I have installed Devise for authentication and followed [this guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template) to include sign up and log in links in my views.

Here's what I did in my `application.html.erb`:

```
<ul class="hmenu">
  <%= render 'devise/menu/registration_items' %>
  <%= render 'devise/menu/login_items' %>
</ul>
```

And my `views/devise/menu/_login_item.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path) %>        
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>  
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Now I get the following error message:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Home#index
Missing partial devise/menu/login_items with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Users/blah/Documents/webapp/mapeval/app/views", "/Users/blah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.3/app/views"
```

What is the cause of that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partial has invalid filename (missing **s** at the end). Rename `views/devise/menu/_login_item.html.erb` to `views/devise/menu/_login_items.html.erb`